# Are there advantages to declaring stack variables constant in C++

Tags: c++, const

It's not clear to me what benefits there are of declaring your stack variables as constant in C++, I was hoping somebody might explain the benefits and purpose for this technique.

For example:

```
void func(const std::string& arg)
{
   if(someCondition)
   {
      const std::string foo ("some string plus " + arg);
      std::out << foo << std::endl;
      someFunction(foo);
      // dozens more lines of code...
   }
   // bla bla bla...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

1. It helps the reader to understand your intent. Clearly foo is given an initial value and never changed thereafter.
2. It helps the compiler to optimise your code, for both speed and space. The compiler can perform certain optimisations such as hoisting values out of loops if there is a promise that the value cannot change. This is particularly the case if the value has an alias, which would otherwise defeat optimisation.
3. It occasionally catches bugs, when you accidentally write code to modify something you didn't mean to.

On the down side, you may not be able to pass the value into a function that takes non-const arguments.

Comment: do you have any reference for 2, my understanding was that this isn't true as 1) compilers can do this optimization regardless of if the variable is actually marked const, 2) const only promises a logical constness i.e. there can actually be mutation 3) the ability to cast away const means all bets are off

Comment: A quick web search found dozens, mostly right here on SO. Try this for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212237/constants-and-compiler-optimization-in-c

Comment: and I can find many saying it doesn't help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313730/does-const-correctness-give-the-compiler-more-room-for-optimization - I do take the point that it at least allows the compiler to potentially optimize

Comment: @jk.: the answer to this question includes an example (3rd code block) that is exactly what I had in mind. Aliasing (pointer to declared variable) prevents the compiler optimising; const allows it to do so. Not much point pursuing this further -- it's been done to death. Suggest you ask the GCC authors.

Comment: @everyone: Implementation-defined behavior is implementation-defined. Just because one compiler can optimize it does not mean all can.

Comment: @Snowman: Actually, the behaviour of this particular piece of code is defined by the standard. I can't see anything "implementation-defined" here. And a const declaration very often means that a compiler _can_ apply an optimisation; whether it _will_ depends on lots of factors and is way beyond scope.

Comment: @david.pfx the standard doesn't really say how _anything_ should be implemented, only that the compiler must obey certain semantics. In other words, no matter how the compiled code looks, it must behave a certain way. This is what I mean when I talk about optimizations: the compiler is free to do a lot of things, as long as the _behavior_ is per the standard. This could include (as the question says) hoisting a variable outside a loop as long as it obeys scope rules.

Comment: @Snowman: Of course. But the standard also specifies that certain things are "implementation defined" and those things are not present in this question, this sample or my answer.

Comment: @david.pfx yeah, I think using that specific term muddied the water a bit. It would be more appropriate to say that compilers have a bit of leeway in how code is compiled, since "implementation-defined" has a specific meaning per the standard.

Comment: @Snowman: Yes, that's all I meant. At least with "implementation-defined" they have to tell you what they did. Things like optimisation they often don't tell you and you have to reverse engineer the compiler to find out.